# How should I represent a UI state change in the URL?

Tags: web-applications, state, url

My web application has a UI. Some aspects of the UI can be changed (e.g. the language, the theme, the text size). As a concrete example, let's assume that I have a "theme" dropdown box available on every page.

Now, when a user changes the theme, the current page should reload with the new theme, and the new theme should be used for all subsequent page calls. In other words, I want to (a) change some server-side state (the session variable containing the theme name) and (b) reload the page.

I know how to implement this. In fact, I know *more than one way* to implement this, and this bugs me. I want to find the *best* way to implement this, and since *best* is subjective, I want to identify the advantages and drawbacks of both options (and maybe learn about alternative solutions that I didn't even think of).

---

Here is solution 1:

- I add the new theme name as a query parameter (i.e. `http://example.com/show_orders?customerId=2` becomes `http://example.com/show_orders?customerId=2&changeTheme=dark`) and reload the page.
- A generic server-side handler checks for the `changeTheme` parameter, updates the state and then execution passes on to the specific handler (`show_orders`), which ignores the unknown `changeTheme` parameter.

What I don't like about this solution is that

- page-specific parameters (`customerId`) and site-specific parameters (`changeTheme`) are mixed and
- "state-changing" parameters are in the URL: If the user sends the URL to a colleague directly after changing the theme, calling the URL will also cause the colleague's theme to change. I don't know if there is a specific term for this, but if just "feels wrong" to have a GET request to a resource called `show_orders` *change* something. (Feel free to correct me, if my gut feeling is wrong here.)

---

Here is solution 2:

- I call a dedicated URL for changing the theme and pass the original page as a parameter, i.e. `http://example.com/change_theme?newTheme=dark&redirectTo=%2Fshow_orders%3FcustomerId=2`.
- The `change_theme` handler changes the session state and then redirects (HTTP 302) to the original URL as defined in the query string parameter.

What I don't like about this solution is that

- I am redirecting back and forth, which *might* affect performance, and
- I am redirecting to a user-supplied value, so I might need to take extra precautions w.r.t. security.

---

Today, I implemented solution 1 and I am considering to change it to solution 2, for the reasons outlined above. Is this a good idea? Are there pros and cons that I have missed? Is there some superior solution 3, which is well-established best industry practice? If yes, what problems does it solve that options 1 and 2 have?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 2 is an well-established practice in the industry, especially when dealing with login screens.

The scenario is then:

- you navigate to an URL for which authentication is needed
- the server redirects you to a login page, but also marks the original endpoint either in the URL or in a hidden form field
- after successful authentication, you are redirected to the page you originally requested.

Also, the pattern POST - redirect - GET is very commonly used when users submit a form to avoid double submissions when the user refreshes the browser page, so the redirect can't have that much of a performance penalty.